# Writing OpenCV CV_8UC3 image matrix into writeable bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv, pixel, writeablebitmap

I have two monochromatic images as byte[] taken from cameras. I want to combine these images and write the combined image into a writeable bitmap.

### Merging images: OpenCV

Using openCV, I create `Mat` objects (of type `CV_8UC1`) from the byte arrays (`greenMat` for the green and `redMat` for the red color channel image) and merge them via `Cv2.Merge`

```
Mat mergedMat = new Mat(greenMat.Height, greenMat.Width, MatType.CV_8UC3);
Mat emptyMat = Mat.Zeros(greenMat.Height, greenMat.Width, MatType.CV_8UC1);
        Cv2.Merge(new[]
        {
            redMat, greenMat, emptyMat
        }, mergedMat);
```

The mergedMat.ToBytes() now retuns a buffer of size 2175338. Why is it this size? Merging three one-channel matrices (CV_8UC1) if size 2448x2048 into one three-channel matrix(CV_8UC3) should yield to a buffer of size 15040512, or am I missing something here?

### Display merged image: WriteableBitmap

I want to display the merged image by writing it into an existing `WriteableBitmap`, that is initialized via

```
ImageSource = new WriteableBitmap(
            width, //of the green image
            height, //of the green image
            96, //dpiX: does not affect image as far as I tested
            96, //dpiY
            PixelFormats.Rgb24, //since the combined image is a three channel color image
            null); //no bitmap palette needed for used PixelFormat
```

Is this initialization correct? I'm unsure about the `PixelFormat` here. The `dpiX` and `dpiY` values also seem to have no effect. What is their use?

The tricky part I can't get to work properly now is to write the image data into the `WriteableBitmap`.

Using the following code to obtain the byte array of the
    merged image and using `WriteableBitmap`s' WritePixels method, with
    stride according to the ImageSources' PixelFormat, yields an
    `System.ArgumentException: 'Buffer size is not sufficient.'`

```
    var mergedBuffer = mergedMat.ToBytes();
    var bytesPerPixel = (PixelFormats.Rgb24.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    var stride = bytesPerPixel * width;

    ((WriteableBitmap)ImageSource).WritePixels(
        new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height),
        mergedBuffer,
        stride,
        0)
```

Edit: Stride is calculated according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29443854/7598462), although it's not neccessary with a fixed `PixelFormat` like here.

Why is the buffer too small? I did initialize the `WriteableBitmap`
    with the correct width and height and `PixelFormats.Rgb24`. Am I
    calculating my stride correctly?

### Solution

Thanks to @Micka s suggestions in the comments I realized the `mergedMat.ToBytes` method seems not to do what I expceted. Instead, I tried to use `mergedMat.Data` pointer like so:

```
var mergedBufferSize = (int)(mergedMat.Total() * mergedMat.Channels());
byte[] mergedBuffer = new byte[mergedBufferSize];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(
  mergedMat.Data,
  mergedBuffer,
  0,
  mergedBufferSize);
```

Everything works fine this way.

Comment: can you explain  var bytesPerPixel = (PixelFormats.Rgb24.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;? Shouldnt it just be BitsPerPixel/8? Can you display BitsPerPixel and bytesPerPixel? For an OpenCV Mat you can fetch the stride with .step method

Comment: The `+7`  is not really necessary here, since the pixel format is fix, but it's there to prevent bytesPerPixel getting `0` if you have a pixel format with less than 8 BitsPerPixel. Got it from some other SO question, but can't find it any more.

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440576/how-do-i-set-a-wpf-images-source-to-a-bytearray-in-c-sharp-code-behind) it is!

Comment: ok, I wouldn't expect pixels to be 1..7 bits of size. If c# rounds integer division to zero it should be ok.Can you display mergedMat.step? This is the stride used by the openCV Mat.

Comment: what's the meaning of Int32Rect here? Will it use 32 bit for each pixel?

Comment: `mergedMat.Step()` is 1836, just as the calculated stride. Nice to know, however, that that's openCVs stride.
The Int32Rect in the `WriteableBitmap.WritePixels` call defines the bitmaps' area to update; since I want to update the whole thing, it's the full size of the image.

Comment: is there any documentation of .ToBytes() method? In C++ you'd just use .data pointer. Is it possible that ToBytes() converts to hex character representation?

Comment: That did it; I edited my answer to include the solution by not calling `ToBytes` but instead using the `mergedMat.Data` pointer.